# AWS: How is CPU utilization calculated for auto scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, autoscaling

I created an Auto Scaling group, with an Application Load Balancer attached, with a policy that when CPU utilization rate is greater than 75% add one more instance. It seems working.

When I have four instances running, how is that CPU Utilization rate calculated? Average of the four instances? Minimum among the four?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created an Auto Scaling Policy and that policy executes when the alarm you had configured is triggered.

[image: Create Alarm]

You can see ***Average*** selected in the dropdown list. Various option that can be selected are *Average*, *Minimum*, *Maximum*, *Sum* and *SampleCount*.

You can also refer to [Scaling Based on Metrics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/policy_creating.html).

Comment: Thanks John that is so obvious isn't it? I am too new to AWS and everything is a bit overwhelming at the moment...